# Float images in content

Tags: editor, media, post-content

This is not a programming question. I have the problem to update the content in my WordPress blog. I'm very aware this problem can be solved by html modification. But my client doesn't know about html.So i need to give him relevant solution.

My Problem :-

I want to show my content as below screen.
[image]

But While i insert a post image content starts at the bottom of the image. This can be solved by html.But i need to know any other easy solution.
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup CSS settings for `alignleft` class of your theme:

```
.alignleft, img.alignleft {
    /* ... */
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    /* ... */
}
```

And you need to add editor stylesheet where the same CSS will be presented. Create `editor-style.css` file in your theme, put content CSS settings there and call `add_editor_style();` from you functions.php file.

Comment: i was JUST about to post this very same question. Great thanks